# Trying to get file name of the largest file

Tags: java

So I am learning recursion right now and I know how to get the largest file size in a folder that's chosen in JFileChooser.

I just can't for the life of me can't figure out how to get the name of that file after it's found. Here's the method to getting the largestFileSize. How would I go about getting the name of that file?

```
public static long largestFileSize(File f) {
    if (f.isFile()) {
        return f.length();
    } else {
        long largestSoFar = -1;

        for (File file : f.listFiles()) {
            largestSoFar = Math.max(largestSoFar, largestFileSize(file));
        }
        return largestSoFar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
String fileName = file.getName()
```

Since it's impractical to return both the size of a file and the name, why don't you return the File and then get its size and name from that?

```
public static File largestFile(File f) {
    if (f.isFile()) {
        return f;
    } else {
        File largestFile = null;

        for (File file : f.listFiles()) {
            // only recurse largestFile once
            File possiblyLargeFile = largestFile(file);
            if (possiblyLargeFile != null) {
                if (largestFile == null || possiblyLargeFile.length() > largestFile.length()) {
                    largestFile = possiblyLargeFile;
                }
            }
        }
        return largestFile;
    }
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
String largestFileName = largestFile(file).getName();
long largestFileSize = largestFile(file).length();
```

**EDIT**: Returns largest `File` in any of the subdirectories. Returns `null` if no files exist in the subdirectories.

Comment: That won't always return the largest file... it can also return the directory that contains the largest file!

Comment: Added `!isDirectory()`. Thanks!

Comment: But now it simply ignores the largest file if it's contained in a directory!

Comment: Actually that can't happen because `largestFile()`'s if condition always returns a `File`

Comment: Yes it can. Look at your code. When you assign `file` to `largestFile`, `file` can be a directory.

Comment: Good. But you're doing the same recursion twice, unnecessarily. It would really be better to only call `largestFile(file)` once. I would recommend storing the result in a variable.

Comment: This got it! I never thought of just having a method where it's just returning a file, then later on just call the .length() and the .getName(); later on when I need it. I have much to learn! Thanks!

Comment: Any reason why I'm getting a NullPointerException? Some folders don't throw the exception, but most do.

Comment: Just before the inner if statement, check if possiblyLargestFile is null and continue if it is. Now it should only return the largest file and null if there are no files, only directories.

Comment: Just updated it. Tested it will empty directories, large files in directories, etc. Returns null if there are no files in a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
public static File largestFile(File f) {
    if (f.isFile()) {
        return f;
    } else {
        long largestSoFar = -1;
        File largestFile = null;
        for (File file : f.listFiles()) {
            file = largestFile(file);
            if (file != null) {
                long newSize = file.length();
                if (newSize > largestSoFar) {
                    largestSoFar = newSize;
                    largestFile = file;
                }
            }
        }
        return largestFile;
    }
}
```

then call:

```
largestFile(myFile).getName();
```